# Ubuntu 18.04 Does Not Accept "\" or any other appropriate character in paths

Tags: samba, paths

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a former Windows 7 laptop. When trying to connect a printer belonging to a Windows computer on my network through Samba, I find I cannot insert spaces into the path using the usual special character prefixes; the special characters do nothing to the input line. I have already achieved this printer link from my other Ubuntu laptop, which runs an earlier version of Ubuntu.

So has something dramatically changed with 18.04? or am I doing something wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want help to find out if you did something wrong, you'd better show us what you did. So please edit your question and add details on what you did and exactly what happened that did not meet your expectations. (I'm not aware of a dramatic change in this respect.)

Comment: I didn't do anything because I wasn't allowed to. Just follow "Add windows printer via samba" and you'll find out (if you're running 18.04). I said that I had connected to the printer successfully with an earlier version of Ubuntu. The problem is the dialog not accepting the "\" character preceding the <space>, which it also does not accept.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem. Escape characters are not accepted. To insert a space, type "%20".

Comment: Remember to come back in one day and click the grey check mark next to your answer so others know it works. Thanks.